# How to make single div with contents to fill entire page when printed

Tags: html, css, aurelia

I have an aurela app that needs to be able to print out labels. On the page with the form there is a hidden div that contains the layout of the label. I want to print only the hidden div and i want it to be stretched(with content) to be ful size of the page in landscape. Currently it only fills a small corner of the page.

JSFiddle [Label](https://jsfiddle.net/vastrolorde/7fmcgh6r/)

This is the CSS i have tryed to get it working. Weird thing is changes to the @page does nothing. I tryed different page sizes but nothing affects the div, it still sits in the one corner.

```
    @media print {
  header, footer, .print-hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  @page {
    size: auto;
    margin: 0mm;
  }

  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .print-show{
    display: block;

    position: absolute;

    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
  }
}
```

This is the aurelia template for the label

```
<template bindable="firstname, lastname, company, inviter, uniquecode">
<div class="label-container">
<div class="row justify-content-start mx-0 px-1 pt-1">
    <div class="text-center">
        <img class="label-logo" src="image.png">
        <div class="visitor-logo">VISITOR</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-row text-center label-name">
    <div>${firstname}</div>
    <div>${lastname}</div>
</div>
<div class="text-center label-company">
    ${company}
</div>
<div class="row justify-content-between mx-0 px-1">
    <div>
        <div class="label-guestof">Guest of</div>
        <div class="label-inviter">${inviter}</div>
    </div>
    <span>${uniquecode}</span>
</div>
</div>
```

And here are the custom css classes for the label:

```
    .label-container{
  width: 350px;
  height: 188px;
}

.visitor-logo{
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #505659;
}

.label-name{
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #2B3033;
}

.label-company{
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #737B80;
}

.label-guestof{
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #737B80;
}

.label-inviter{
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #505659;
}

.label-logo{
  height: 28px;
  width: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? Create a stack snippet or a JSFiddle.

Comment: @Jake added JSFiddle. I dont know much about JSFiddle but i hope its enough. the ${...} is aurelias one-way bind.

Comment: Simply set `.label-container` to `width: 100%; height: 100%;` in your print media-query ?

Comment: @Jake well this fixed the width issue, but height issue remainde, but it seems there are some problems with the way i have made the css stylings... i need to find someone who is experienced in CSS and help me to create the proper layout for this thing...

Answer (score 0):

I restyled it a little bit and added a background color for a better check. I hope this is what you're seeking. If not is was kinda fun to do it :P.

```
<!--index.html-->
<div class="label-container">
  <div class="label-container__header mx-0 px-1 pt-1">
    <div class="text-center">
      <img class="label-logo" src="image.png">
      <div class="visitor-logo">VISITOR</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="label-container__names label-name">
    <div>${firstname}</div>
    <div>${lastname}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="label-container__company label-company">
    ${company}
  </div>
  <div class="label-container__footer justify-content-between mx-0 px-1">
    <div>
      <div class="label-guestof">Guest of</div>
      <div class="label-inviter">${inviter}</div>
    </div>
    <span>${uniquecode}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
// style.css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.label-container {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.label-container__header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.label-container__names {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.label-container__company {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.label-container__footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.visitor-logo{
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #505659;
}

.label-name{
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #2B3033;
}

.label-company{
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #737B80;
}

.label-guestof{
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #737B80;
}

.label-inviter{
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #505659;
}

.label-logo{
  height: 28px;
  width: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Some new information. The paper on which it gets printed is in the scale of 50mmX94mm. If the label is printed out it shuld be in landscape on the label, and it should fill the lable nicely :D If the layout is set i can fix the scales of fonts and images myself.

Comment: `.label-container {
  width: 94%;
  height: 55%;
  ...
}`

This should have the right ratio then

Comment: Yes this works, but onyl in Fireforx. Both Chrome and IE are messed up. While FF puts everything on 1 page. IE and Chrome spreads the content out to 14 pages.

Comment: Okay, that's weird.. I have coded and tested for chrome canary. :P

Comment: I checked also on Chrome canary, same result. It feels like the chrome printing system cannot handle flex boxes and flex rows.

Comment: HMM weird, at the company I work ATM, we use chromium and almost everywhere flex boxes and rows. Sorry I can't help you out :(

Comment: Atleast you helped to get me somewhere. It works in Firefox, so there is that.And browser vs what gets printed vs what print preview sees are all different things. If one works, doesent mean that the other work also.