# Print layout works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a webpage that prints out tickets. I need the layout to correctly fill the paper. Im currently using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022763/how-to-make-single-div-with-contents-to-fill-entire-page-when-printed/56066730?noredirect=1#comment99061600_56066730) offered by LittleGnome. It works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome and IE the layout is messed up. The scale is too big and the content is spread over 4 pieces of paper instead of one.

When i used chromes dev tools to debug the print layout, it seemed like chrome cannot handle the flex containers correctly. All the elements on the layout have a size of 8000X4000 pixels, which is totally wrong. What might be causing this and how to fix this?

[JsFiddle for the current version](https://jsfiddle.net/vastrolorde/e9znbLqw/2/)

Comment: Would be more helpful if you can add your html and css code to see the problem

Comment: @StefanJoseph Added JsFiddle